# eclipse ee and tomcat 7 - how to add library.path

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I installed on windows eclipse ee 4.3, added existing tomcat 7 as server.

How can I add -Djava.library.path parameter to starting command of tomcat 7, when I start it from eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Run` -> `Run Configurations...` double click on Apache Tomcat and choose `Arguments` tab. There is `VM arguments` textarea where you can put additional arguments.

Comment: thanks, i used to Tomcat Launcher plugin and they have the things in Prefs/tomcat/JVM Settings